# Copy command in html for chrome to copy multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a note pad that is to help keep notes consistent between users. I am unable to copy the multiple text boxes to a string. I have attached all of my Java Script.

The copy button that I would like to use to link the multiple text boxes into one string of text. the reset button works at clearing the page and the copy button follows the not empty text box checks. Please help with my copy string to the clipboard.

I have tried a bunch of different sites on the java script with no success. I have also reviewed Stack Overflow to see if I could find a close project.

```
input type="button" id="BtnSupSubmit" value="Copy" onclick="notEmptySup()" style="width: 87px"
```

```
  function settime() {
    var curtime = new Date();
    var curhour = curtime.getHours();
    var curmin = curtime.getMinutes();
    var time = "";

    if (curhour == 0) curhour = 12;
    time = (curhour > 12 ? curhour - 12 : curhour) + ":" +
     (curmin < 10 ? "0" : "") + curmin + ":" +
     (curhour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");

    document.date.clock.value = time;
    clock = time
    window.status = time
}

function notEmptySup() {
    var myTextField = document.getElementById('TxtBoxCallersName');
    if (myTextField.value != "") notEmptySup2()
    else
        alert("Please enter callers name.")
}
function notEmptySup2() {
    var myTextField = document.getElementById('TxtBoxSupIssue');
    if (myTextField.value != "") notEmptySup3()
    else
        alert("Please enter the reason for the escalation.")
}
function notEmptySup3() {
    var myTextField = document.getElementById('TxtBoxSupAction');
    if (myTextField.value != "") notEmptySup4()
    else
        alert("Please enter the action you took to help the customer.")
}
function notEmptySup4() {
    var myTextField = document.getElementById('TxtBoxSupResolution');
    if (myTextField.value != "") CreateMessage()
    else
        alert("Please enter the resolution of the call.")
}
    function CreateMessage() {

    strMessage =
        "Time: " + clock + "\|" +
        "***Supervisor Escalation" + "\***|" +
        "Caller: " + document.getElementById("TxtBoxCallersName").value + " \| " +
        "Reason: " + document.getElementById("TxtBoxSupIssue").value + " \| " +
        "Action: " + document.getElementById("TxtBoxSupAction").value + " \| " +
        "Resolution: " + document.getElementById("TxtBoxSupResolution").value + " \| " +
        "Ticket Number: " + document.getElementById("TxtBoxSupTicketNumber").value + " \| " +
        "Addl Notes: " + document.getElementById("TxtBoxSupNotes").value;


        document.getElementById("hdnBuffer").value = strMessage;

        var buffer = document.getElementById("hdnBuffer").createTextRange();
        buffer.execCommand("Copy");
    }
```

Comment: *I am trying to do this for Google Chrome as that is the default tool for accessing the internet.* These days, we don't write code for just one browser. Chrome is a standards-based client. If it works in Chrome, it will work in all standards-based clients.

Comment: Now, please edit your post and ask a specific question. All you've done so far is post a bunch of code along with what you'd like it to do. What ***specifically*** are you having a problem with? And, please include all the relevant code... HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: You could comment the clipboard magic and simply `alert` the text you are building. Then you would see both if `CreateMessage` is called at all, and how the string it builds looks like. It is hard to tell more without seeing more of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you have is redundant. See comments inline below:

```js
// Get a reference to the form
let frm = document.querySelector("form")

// Set up a sumbit event handler for the form
frm.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){

  // Just get the locally formatted time
  var message = "Time: " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + 
                "\n***Supervisor Escalation***\n\n";

  // Get all the input elements
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  
  // Loop over them
  for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].value === ""){
      alert("Please enter the " + inputs[i].dataset.message);
      inputs[i].focus();     // Put focus on bad element
      evt.preventDefault();  // Cancel the form submit
      break;                 // Exit the loop
    } else {
      // Update the message
      message += inputs[i].dataset.message + ": " +
                 inputs[i].value + " \n";
    }
  }
  
  alert(message); // Do whatever you want with the message
});
```

```html
<form action="https://example.com" method="post">
  <div><label>Name:<input data-message="callers name"></label></div>
  <div><label>Issue: <input data-message="reason for the escalation"></label></div>
  <div><label>Action: <input data-message="action you took to help the customer"></label></div>
  <div><label>Resolution: <input data-message="resolution of the call"></label></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit Ticket</button>
</form>
```